# Joining to a dimension table just once

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I've got a fact table where we have `OrderId | Arrival_location | Departing_location`.

The dimension table that links to this is fairly basic, something like `LocationID | LocationName`.

To do a query to get both arrival and departing location names, do I have to `join` twice?

```
SELECT 
  OrderId, adm.LocationName, dep.LocationName
FROM 
  fct
LEFT JOIN dim as adm
  ON fct.Arrival_location = adm.LocationID
LEFT JOIN dim as dep
  ON fct.Departing_location = dep.LocationID
```

Or is there a way to do this with just one `left join`?

Comment: You need to join both columns.

Comment: Technically you can use aggregation with a single `join`, but I would think your query would be faster with the multiple `joins`.  Here's an example of aggregation though: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee3e7/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two joins because the departure and arrival locations are **independent values**.

Let's rewrite your query a bit to illustrate.  I'll also change the `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN` because it will make the point clearer:

```
SELECT 
  OrderId, adm.LocationName, dep.LocationName
FROM 
  fct
INNER JOIN dim
  ON fct.Arrival_location = dim.LocationID
  AND fct.Departing_location = dim.LocationID
```

In this query you're joining to `dim` only once.  But you're saying that:

- `fct.Arrival_location = dim.LocationID`
- `fct.Departing_location = dim.LocationID`

And logically it follows from those two that:

- `fct.Arrival_location = fct.Departing_location`

So to express the logic that you want for your query, you need `adm.LocationID` and `dep.LocationID` to stand for **two potentially different** `LocationID` values.  The way this works in SQL is that by having two different aliases of the same table you get a similar effect as if you had two identical "copies" of the table.  Each row in your result set corresponds to an independent choice of values for each of the "copies."  So my query works like this:

- For each row in `fct`:

  - For each row in `dim`:
  - If the pair of rows satisfies the conditions, output a row for that combination.

Whereas in your query:

- For each row in `fct`:

  - For each row in `dim`, aliased as `adm`:
  - For each row in `dim`, aliased as `dep`:
  - If the combination of rows satisfies the conditions (taking the `LEFT JOIN` part into consideration), output a row for that combination.

So with the extra join it considers all *combinations* of pairs of locations.